# Convert character from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 manually

Tags: utf-8, iso-8859-1, latin1

I have the character "ö". If I look in [this UTF-8 table](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepage-utf8.php) I see it has the hex value `F6`. If I look in the [Unicode table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) I see that "ö" has the indices `E0`and `16`. If I add both I get the hex value of the code point of `F6`. This is the binary value  `1111 0110`.

1) How do I get from the hex value `F6` to the indices `E0` and `16`?
2) I don't know how to come from `F6` to the two bytes `C3` `B6` ...

Because I didn't got the results I tried to go the other way. "ö" is represented in ISO-8859-1 as "Ã¶". In the [UTF-8 table](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepage-utf8.php) I can see that "Ã" has the decimal value `195` and "¶" has the decimal value `182`. Converted to bits this is `1100 0011 1011 0110`.

**Process:**

1. Look in a [table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) and get the unicode for the character "ö". Calculated from the indices `E0` and `16` you get the Unicode `U+00F6`.
2. According to the algorithm posted by wildplasser you can calculate the coded UTF-8 value `C3` and `B6`.
3. In the binary form you get `1100 0011 1011 0110` which corresponds to the decimal values `195` and `182`.
4. If these values are interpreted as [ISO 8859-1](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepage-utf8.php) (only 1 byte) then you get "Ã¶".

PS: I found also [this link](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/), which shows the values from step 2.

Comment: You want to convert in both directions? BTW: you don't convert from utf8 to iso9959-1. You convert form utf8 to the binary value of it's code point, and represent it in 8 bits. That this codepoint should be interpreted as latin1 does not matter.

Comment: You'll find it much easier if you go through UTF-16 first. In UTF-8, you have E0/16. This converts to F6 according to the UTF-8 algorithm. You then look up U+00F6 in the ISO-8859-1 table, which is at position F6.

Comment: @wildplasser:
If I know one direction the other should not be a problem I think. Because I didn't got the desired result with the first try, I made another try (the other way round). No I edited my question and added the binary value of the code point. But how can I interpret it in Latin1 now?

@RaymondChen:
[This is the ISO-8859-1 table](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/latin1.gif) I use. But I currently don't know how to come to the two bytes `C3` and `B6`.

Comment: ö in Latin-1 is not "represented as Ã¶". ö in Latin-1 is represented using the single byte 0xF6, or `1111 0110`. If you interpret the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence for ö, namely 0xC3B6 (`1100 0011 1011 0110`) in Latin-1, you get the two characters Ã (0xC3) and ¶ (0xB6) of the Latin-1 encoding. May I recommend [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) (not the same as linked to by @Avi)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pages you are using are confusing you somewhat. Neither your "UTF-8 table" or "Unicode table" are giving you the value of the code point in UTF-8. They are both simply listing the Unicode value of the characters.

In Unicode, every character ("code point") has a unique number assigned to it. The character `ö` is assigned the code point `U+00F6`, which is `F6` in hexadecimal, and `246` in decimal.

UTF-8 is a [representation](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8) of Unicode, using a sequence of between one and four bytes per Unicode code point. The transformation from 32-bit Unicode code points to UTF-8 byte sequences is described in that article - it is pretty simple to do, once you get used to it. Of course, computers do it all the time, but you can do it with a pencil and paper easily, and in your head with a bit of practice.

If you do that transformation, you will see that `U+00F6` transforms to the UTF-8 sequence `C3 B6`, or `1100 0011  1011 0110` in binary, which is why that is the UTF-8 representation of `ö`.

The other half of your question is about ISO-8859-1. This is a character encoding commonly called "[Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)". The numeric values of the Latin-1 encoding are the same as the first 256 code points in Unicode, thus `ö` is `F6` in Latin-1.

Once you have converted between UTF-8 and standard Unicode code points (UTF-32), it should be trivial to get the Latin-1 encoding. However, not all UTF-8 sequences / Unicode characters have corresponding Latin-1 characters.

See the excellent article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for a better understanding of character encodings and transformations between them.

Comment: Yeah, I read the article before I started to do the encoding. I thin [this link](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) shows the code point in UTF-8 very well. Thanks to wildplasser I'm able to convert between UTF-8 and Unicode code points. But you delivered a good summary of the topic! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned cha_latin2utf8(unsigned char *dst, unsigned cha)
{
if (cha <  0x80)  { *dst = cha; return 1; }
    /* all 11 bit codepoints (0x0 -- 0x7ff)
      ** fit within a 2byte utf8 char
      ** firstbyte = 110 +xxxxx := 0xc0 + (char>>6) MSB
      ** second    = 10 +xxxxxx := 0x80 + (char& 63) LSB
      */
    *dst++ = 0xc0 | (cha >>6) & 0x1f; /* 2+1+5 bits */
    *dst++ = 0x80 | (cha) & 0x3f; /* 1+1+6 bits */

return 2; /* number of bytes produced */
}
```

To test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
char buff[12];

cha_latin2utf8 ( buff, 0xf6);

fprintf(stdout, "%02x %02x\n"
    , (unsigned) buff[0] & 0xff
    , (unsigned) buff[1] & 0xff );

return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
c3 b6
```

Comment: Is this pseudo code or real working C++ code? Can you explain your answer in more in detail and what your function does? It takes the (later) latin1 converted character and the character which should be converted as input. Than you look if it has a size of one byte (ASCII) and return it. If it has two bytes you create two bytes which are the MSB and the LSB after the rules of UTF-8. What is the MSB/LSB in my example? OK I figured it out. The function takes `F6` as input (cha) and creates the MSB `C3` and LSB `B6`. So now I can calculate in the other way too.

Comment: Yes, it is working C code. To test it, just plug your F6 value into the 'cha' argument and see what happens. You can do this in your head, or on paper. The result **should** be your E0 and 16 values.

Comment: Actually, it was not (yet) working, because I snipped a line too few.

Comment: I didn't test it but I played with it in mind. So question no. 2 is answered. What about question no. 1? Is it an addition or is it an own algorithm like mentioned from Raymond? Can the indices be calculated (input F6, output E0 and 16) or is it a lookup table?

Comment: The E0 and 16 values are just the intermediates, the original F6 value split into the upper 3 and the lower 5 bits. The upper (MSB) 3 bits are shifted down and become 3 and are combined with the C0 constant, the right 5 (actually 6, but the upmost bit is zero) bits are or'd with the 0x80 mask.